# On functors agreeing with the powerset functor on objects and not being isomorphic to it

Tags: category-theory, functors, yoneda-lemma

Recall the powerset functor $\mathcal{P}:\mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}$ defined as

- $\mathcal{P}(X) = 2^{X} = \{U\subseteq X\}$ on objects
- $\mathcal{P}(f: X \to Y): \mathcal{P}(X) \to \mathcal{P}(Y),\ \ \ \mathcal{P}(f)(U) = f(U)$ on morphisms

> Are there functors  $\mathcal{F}:\mathbf{Set}\to \mathbf{Set}$ agreeing with $\mathcal{P}$ on objects, i.e. $\mathcal{F}(X) = \mathcal{P}(X)$ for all sets $X$?

This question was answered in ["Is power set functor determined by its image on objects?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3372859/is-power-set-functor-determined-by-its-image-on-objects/3372907#comment6940441_3372907).

However, all functors given there are naturally isomorphic to $\mathcal{P}$.

> **Question:** Are there any such functors which are *not* naturally isomorphic to $\mathcal{P}$?

---

### Summary of Results

All functors given in the question linked above can be succinctly characterized as follows:

> For each set $X$ choose a bijection $r_X\colon \mathcal P(X)\to\mathcal P(X)$. Now let your functor $\mathcal F$ be defined on morphisms $f\colon X\to Y$ by
>   $$\mathcal F(f) = r_Y\circ \mathcal P(f) \circ r_X^{-1}$$
>
> One non-trivial choice of $r_X$ would be taking complements, i.e. $r_X(U)=X\setminus U$, then $\mathcal Ff(U) = Y\setminus f(X\setminus U)$.
>
> (source: [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3372907/85341) by [Christoph](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/86801/christoph))

As per my comment on Christoph's post, we can exhibit the natural isomorphism to $\mathcal{P}$ as follows:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
  \mathcal{P}(X) @>{r_X}>> \mathcal{P}(X)\\
  @V{\mathcal{P}f}VV @VV{\mathcal{F}f = r_y\ \circ\ \mathcal{P}f\ \circ\ r_X^{-1}}V \\
  \mathcal{P}(Y) @>{r_Y}>> \mathcal{P}(Y)\end{CD}
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be quite a lot of literature on functors from sets to sets that are determined, up to isomorphism, by their values on objects ("DVO functors").

I found a paper (reference below) which essentially contained the following example to show that the power set functor is not.

Define a functor $F$ such that $FX=\mathcal{P}(X)$ for every set $X$, and for a function $f:X\to Y$, $Ff:\mathcal{P}(X)\to\mathcal{P}(Y)$ is the function such that, for $A\subseteq X$, $Ff(A)=f(A)$ if the restriction of $f$ to $A$ is injective, and $Ff(A)=\emptyset$ if the restriction of $f$ to $A$ is not injective.

*Cancila, Daniela; Honsell, Furio; Lenisa, Marina*, [**Functors determined by values on objects**](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571066106001630), Brookes, Steve (ed.) et al., Proceedings of the 22nd annual conference on mathematical foundations of programming semantics (MFPS XXII), Genova, Italy, May 23–27, 2006. Amsterdam: Elsevier. Electronic Notes in Theoretical Computer Science 158, 151-169 (2006).

Comment: Spot on! It's theorem 5.2 in the linked open-access paper.